# Automate the update of packages in pyproject.toml from virtualenv or pip-tools

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, pyproject.toml, pip-tools

I am trying to update my Python CI environment and am working on package management right now.  I have several reasons that I do not want to use Poetry; however, one nice feature of poetry is the fact that it automatically updates the `pyproject.toml` file.  I know that pip-tools can create a `requirements.txt` file from the `pyproject.toml` file; however, is there any feature within `virtualenv` or `pip-tools` that will enable an automatic update of the `pyproject.toml` file when you install a package with pip to your virtual environment?

Comment: What is the build back-end? Is it `setuptools`?

Comment: @sinoroc yes setup tools is my backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard tool-agnostic `add` command does not exist.

It is being discussed here: https://discuss.python.org/t/poetry-add-but-for-pep-621/22957

I do not know if there is such a feature in `pip-tools`. I am pretty sure it does not exist in `virtualenv`, that would be quite out of scope.

Your can always adopt a "dev workflow tool" (PDM, Hatch, Poetry`*`) if you want it.

---

`*`: Poetry uses a non-standard notation for the project metadata, but you seem to be currently using the standard notation (aka PEP621) so this could be a step backward if you were to migrate to Poetry.

Comment: Your answer is what I expected. I was hoping against all hope that pip-tools offered the desired functionality, but I do not think it does. I'm considering the possibility of just writing a bash script as a wrapper around pip that will automate the update of the toml file, but wanted to avoid this extra work.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. I know that post python 3.8 is driving a lot of changes in the necessary configuration files. However, ultimately if I can capture all of my package requirements in the toml file, there is no longer a need for the requirements.txt file or a lock file. Am I incorrect in my understanding?

Comment: `pyproject.toml` is used for many things. If you mean the `[project]` section, then it is about specifying the metadata for a redistributable package that you want to build (sdists and wheels), and in this metadata is a list of dependencies, yes. But that is not the same purpose as `requirements.txt`, which is also not the same as a lock file. You can read [this](https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/), although it is a bit outdated but if you substitute `setup.py` with `pyproject.toml`, it should still make sense.

Comment: I guess you can "*mis-use*" the `pyproject.toml` and in particular the `dependencies` field of its `[project]` section to replace a `requirements.txt` (or a lockfile), maybe that fits your expectations well enough after all, also I do not know how you used `requirements.txt` before so I really can just guess here. -- I do not know what you mean regarding Python 3.8.